# Expression of a holomorphic function.

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following exercise:

> Suppose $f:\mathbb{C^{*}}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic. Show that if $f(z)\rightarrow \infty$ when $z\rightarrow 0$ and $f(z)\rightarrow \infty$ when $z\rightarrow \infty$, then $f(z)$ can be written in the form: $f(z)=\dfrac{a_k}{z^k}+...+\dfrac{a_1}{z}+a_0+b_1z+...+b_lz^l$

Before I have solved an exercise that in my opinion is similar and said the following:

> Show that if $f$ is entire and $\text{lim}_{z\rightarrow\infty}f(z)=\infty$ then $f$ is a polynomial.

I have solved this exercise using the Casorati-Weierstrass theorem, I have tried to see if the same strategy works to solve the exercise I have, but I cannot conclude anything. I hope you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: I think "$f$ is [integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer)" should be "$f$ is [entire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function)" (or "$f$ is integral", though I've never heard that term).

Comment: @Mark Yes you are correct, thanks

Comment: $f$ has a *pole* at the origin of some order $k$. What can you say about $z^k f(z)$?

Comment: @MartinR that in his Laurent series expansion, the terms of degree less than k vanish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first condition $\lim_{z \to 0} f(z) = \infty$ implies that $f$ has a pole at the origin. Let $k$ be the order of that pole. Then $g(z) = z^kf(z)$ has a removable singularity at the origin and therefore can be extended holomorphically to an entire function.

Now use the other condition $\lim_{z \to\infty} f(z) = \infty$ to show that $g$ is a polynomial, so that $f(z) = g(z)/z^k$ has the desired form.

Comment: Thank you very much, understood, I just have a doubt, I am trying to understand the part of: "and therefore can be extended holomorphically to an entire function.", I think I remember this result and it was derived from Liouville's theorem, but I'm not sure, It has a specific name or a bibliography that you could recommend to me to consult, please.

Comment: @Haus: $g$ is holomorphic in $\Bbb C \setminus \{ 0 \}$ and has a removable singularity at $z=0$. That means that $g$ can be extended holomorphically over $z=0$, i.e. to a function which is holomorphic in all of $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Thank you very much, just one last doubt, the coefficients $a_k$ and $b_k$ are those corresponding to Laurent's series representation of the function g or to those of f?

Comment: @Haus: Your question is unclear to me. $g$ is a polynomial, i.e. $g(z) = c_0 + c_1 z + \ldots c_n z^n$ for some $n$ and some coefficients $c_j$. Then $f(z) = c_0/z^k + \ldots + c_n z^{n-k}$ is of the desired form.